# Arduino Uno "MEM CHECK FAIL" error

Tags: arduino-uno

Just followed [a tutorial](http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf) on how to set up ESP8266 with my Arduino Uno R3. I have a serial connection and get a response of the Arduino but I'm stuck now at chapter "first commands".

I have successfully issued the `AT` command and also the `AT+RST` command and got a response. BUT, the response return was "invalid" at its end instead of "ready". Also theres an output "MEM CHECK FAIL!!!"

```
AT


OK
AT+RST


OK

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,4)

load 0x40100000, len 1396, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0x89
load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, room 4 
tail 4
chksum 0xe8
load 0x3ffe8308, len 540, room 4 
tail 8
chksum 0xc0
csum 0xc0

2nd boot version : 1.4(b1)
  SPI Speed      : 40MHz
  SPI Mode       : QIO
  SPI Flash Size & Map: 8Mbit(512KB+512KB)
jump to run user1 @ 1000

ÃÕMEM CHECK FAIL!!! <<----------------------------- ???
äslrô
Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd.

invalid <<----------------------------------------- should be "ready"
```

Can anyone explain me what that means? Do I have to (re)flash the firmware? And also - are the instructions all the same? I have bought mine from China but it was sold at the same ESP8266 module on Amazon.

Comment: The invalid on the end means that your config on the chip is either corrupted or not set up yet. So that's not part of your memcheck problem

Answer (score 1):

http://www.agcross.com/2015/09/the-esp8266-wifi-chip-part-1-up-and-running/

According to the tutorial it's an undocumented bug with no fix.

If you change the name, baud, and set up the wifi and password you should be good to go